# How to make tab bar background transparent by viewing only tab bar icons?

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I have an image view behind a tab bar with an image set. How to make the tab bar transparent so that I can see the image behind through the tab bar. The tab bar should only display tab bar icons.

Comment: `UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.backgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor())
```